# How to switch iframe in protractor when there are multiple iframes

Tags: iframe, protractor

I have two iframes in my application whereas I need to switch to second iframe using protractor scripting.

[image: NEED to switch to the highlighted iframe]

Comment: please post what have you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `switchTo` method to focus to a frame.

```
// Switch to iframe. Don't forget to provide your iframe's selector
await browser.switchTo().frame(YOUR_IFRAME_SELECTOR);
```